# Are we permitted to discuss software under NDA if the NDA is partly lifted?

Tags: discussion, questions, legal

In the past, Stack Overflow has closed questions about new software that is currently under [NDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement).

However, [Apple has partly lifted the NDA on iOS 8](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/), allowing developers to discuss the APIs in public.

Are we permitted to ask questions about iOS 8?

Comment: Stack-exchange does not police NDAs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488

Comment: Whether it's enforced or not, the legality is relevant to many users, even if there's no associated Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: I think you should ask apple, but since it is sometimes a long procedure to deal with big corporate companies' lawyers, I would say just skip the grey area to be sure. I imagine that you would not like to spend the time with the court in worst case.

Comment: If you are using acronym than at least once provide information what you mean by that acronym . I know this can be found easy. But the explanation of acronym  will makes your post (in general) much more readable. NDA - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement or use link (NDA)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement]. Thank you.

Comment: @boucekv if the reader doesnt know what NDA is, you want to avoid them getting into the question, not explain them what NDA is. Its like asking a question about a [java] JSP and explaining that its a "JavaServer Page"

Comment: @bouc, every human being on earth knows what an NDA is.   BTW Jack, why didn't you just say in the title "can we discuss iOS8 now?"

Comment: @JoeBlow http://xkcd.com/1053/

Comment: @ZigMandel: of course, **everyone** knows that JSP stands for [Jackson Structured Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Structured_Programming), it's so obvious that it's so silly to have to include what it stands for on every questions.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

"Permitted"? Yes and no. Yes in the sense that we really don't care because it is not Stack Overflow's responsibility to enforce or investigate non-disclosure agreements, but no in the sense that you shouldn't *morally* be asking about things if you are bound by a non-disclosure agreement.

**We can't tell you if a question will violate whatever agreement you're under.** Nor should we. We're not lawyers. So if you want to ask, we won't close your question. Moderators actively delete annoying comments about NDAs (and sometimes reopen questions which were closed for solely that reason). However, we also can't guarantee that Apple (or whomever holds the NDA in question) won't take action against you in the future if the post does, in fact, violate an agreement.

**More Information:** [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors)

Comment: All in all, if you want to know whether or not a specific question will violate any agreement, you should be asking Apple or an attorney, not us. We **can not** tell you that. Extra emphasis on **can not**.

Comment: Would the specific question - "Is blah blah okay to talk about now" - okay for a site like Programmers (as a question, not a meta question), if it's a big enough thing (like the above, ios 8) that lots of programmers would reasonably be able to answer in general terms? Or is it completely disallowed due to concerns about legal liability.

Comment: Hell's bells, joe -- animus just exactly answered your question, directly above your comment, heh

Comment: @JoeBlow Not at all. animuson appears to be addressing the moderation position on meta sites. Joe is specifically asking about non-meta sites -- whether it could be appropriate for users to discuss it admits themselves as it is an issue relevant to programmers in general. (The answer in that case would be: I don't think that's on-topic for Programmers, but if one of those sites about IP law ever makes it out of Area 51, it might fit.) And, in fact, Brad Larson just gave a very useful answer down below, so it seems it's we **can** have a productive discussion about the topic after all!

Answer (score 11):

I'll refer you to [my previous answer on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49366/135615), and animuson hits the key points here. Stack Exchange and moderators have no role in enforcing a nondisclosure agreement between a developer and a company. Questions should not be closed because someone believes they violate some kind of legal agreement, and ones that were [were closed in error](https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/378262927603539971).

This comes up every time that Apple announces new beta products and APIs. I strongly dislike [the vigilante justice that I see forming around questions that might be under NDA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184635/135615), leading to even questions not covered by NDA being downvoted and closed for bogus reasons.

This time around, things are different. I'll once again quote the confidentiality portion of the iOS developer license agreement (as it was publicly available when I posted the first answer linked above, and hasn't changed much):

> **4. Confidentiality.** You agree that any Apple pre-release software (including related documentation and materials) and any information
>   disclosed by Apple to you in connection with Apple Events or Paid
>   Content (defined below) will be considered and referred to as “Apple
>   Confidential Information”. Notwithstanding the foregoing, Apple
>   Confidential Information will not include: (i) information that is
>   generally and legitimately available to the public through no fault or
>   breach of yours, (ii) information that is generally made available to
>   the public by Apple, (iii) information that is independently developed
>   by you without the use of any Apple Confidential Information, (iv)
>   information that was rightfully obtained from a third party who had
>   the right to transfer or disclose it to you without limitation, or (v)
>   any third party software and/or documentation provided to you by Apple
>   and accompanied by licensing terms that do not impose confidentiality
>   obligations on the use or disclosure of such software and/or
>   documentation.

The key part of this is

> Apple
>   Confidential Information will not include: (i) information that is
>   generally and legitimately available to the public through no fault or
>   breach of yours

Well, Apple made publicly available pretty much [all documentation about iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW1), [documentation about Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), etc. and stated that anything covered at WWDC is [considered a public disclosure](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/). It's hard to find anything that is covered by NDA anymore, so even if we did care about the NDA between Apple and developers, only a tiny fraction of the questions posted here would even qualify now. I haven't seen a question yet that contained information not publicly disclosed by Apple somewhere.

Maybe complaining about some specific broken part of beta software wouldn't be the best fit on Stack Overflow (we used to close those as being too localized in time), but Apple engineers themselves are regularly answering Swift and iOS 8 questions here, so I wouldn't worry too much about it any more.