# Question is a Copyright Violation?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, legal

When going through the review queue for suggested edits [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21996359/825757) came up. The edit [completely removed the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5161372) and I rejected it. The reason for the edit was:

> This problem was posted in violation of copyright as it belongs to O'Reilly School of Technology and is a live homework problem still in use. The posting is a violation of OST code of ethics and Digital Copyright law. It should be removed along with all responses immediately. mbronson@oreilly.com

Because this is a bit different than a typical edit I flagged the question. Should I have done anything else? What should one do when this type of edit happens?

Comment: Sounds related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220347/189840

Comment: Here's [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580018/python-help-advanced-objects-special-methods).

Comment: @HansPassant lol it's a duplicate question!? Oh brother `<eye-roll>`!

Comment: I've seen this oreilly doing the same before, but this user only has 1 suggested edit... stange.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this question might not even be covered by copyright. Unless specific wording from the question has been copied, it's likely that what has been taken from the homework (eg if the requirements are paraphrased) is not copyrightable.

Comment: "Removed along with all responses"? Are the answers (C) O'Reilly too?

Comment: All your answers are belong to us.

Comment: @jwg It's likely covered under fair use even if it is word for word, as long as it's asking for help, and just a short excerpt (one question).  Similar to posting a question on a literary review site or similar with an excerpt from a book you're discussing.

Comment: I had never heard of the OST code of ethics before.

Comment: I really enjoy [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24441778): "Failure to do so will result in possible legal action against the poster and **retroactive dismissal from all OST courses and certificates**. Matthew C. Bronson, Academic Director, O'Reilly School of Technology mbronson@oreillyschhol.com 707 827 7144". Note the "retroactive dismissal" and the misspelled domain name in the email address? How exactly do you "retroactively dismiss" someone? Is that like firing them a few weeks ago even though they've worked and you've paid them? And an academic director who can't spell "school"?

Comment: The question has now been deleted.  Was it deleted due to this person's request or for other reasons?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: apparently a DMCA notice was filed.

Comment: Is this circumstance not covered by fair use?

Comment: @JustinMegawarne I believe that fair use would still require acknowledgement of the original source of the text, which was not provided. The author didn't even make it clear that it was copied text (as it appears to be), and not their original summary of a problem. That aside, I'm not sure whether this would count as fair use: it might, but as it's part of a course test, the questions may count as a "substantive" portion of the original work even if they wouldn't be considered so if taken from a different, larger work.

Comment: @KenWhite - to retroactively dismiss someone they A) reset the universal clock back to before that person started their coursework; B) stick a vacuum cleaner into the student's ear and suck out everything they've learned; C) refuse to ever let this person buy a computer-related publication with a black-and-white picture of a little-known animal on the front; and D) they make the student pay for the privilege of having this done. So don't try to mess with the O'Reilly School Of Technology (which is not but really should be based in Ottumwa, Iowa). Really, just don't...

Comment: @JustinMegawarne Even if it falls under fair use, that's not something SE will decide. SE will take it down following a DMCA claim. Then the OP can file a counter claim, arguing for fair use.

Comment: Somewhat related - I recognize MANY questions posted by user1002288 as copy-written material.  But, I am in no position to file a complaint - DMCA or otherwise.  This user has posted 104 questions and has provided ZERO answers and his activity here diminishes SO/SE (IMHO).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Don't bother flagging it. It's not a moderator's job or even the site's job to enforce 3rd party agreements.

If someone wants something taken down, they need to file a DMCA request.

Moderators as well as the majority of users and SE employees are not lawyers and cannot tell the difference between:

1. An actual copyright violation claimed by the copyright owner.
2. A troll impersonating a copyright owner attempting to take something down they don't like.

A DMCA request puts the burden of proof on the party making the take down request.
See Joel Spolsky's answer here for more details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114007

---

If the person tries to make the edit repeatedly, that's just childish vandalism and will warrant a moderator flag.

Comment: I suppose this is for similar or the same reasons why the site [doesn't get involved with enforcing 3rd-party non-disclosure agreements](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260734/are-we-permitted-to-discuss-software-under-nda-if-the-nda-is-partly-lifted).

Comment: The place to _make_ DMCA requests is here: http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#designatedagent

Comment: We have the email of the person allegedly making these edits. Should a moderator send an email to the person pointing towards the site's DMCA policy?

Comment: Thank God the reviewers actually made the right decision on that one.

Comment: Out of curiosity, will anyone even e-mail the person who defaced the post, or is the attitude basically, "This isn't our problem.  Get out of here"?  (Which I totally support, actually.)  Seems like it could be useful to just link the person to this Meta thread.

Comment: Should you remove the email address of the O'Riley rep as this is going to be a popular topic?

Comment: What a crap attitude. You are knowingly violating someone's copyright

Comment: @TFD Not quite. We don't know if the user who made that edit is actually the copyright holder or just a troll trying to deface a question. Requiring the person to file a DMCA will ensure that the person is actually the copyright holder.

Comment: A quick email would short that out. Where is your pride!

Comment: @TFD Honestly, you can't really expect the moderators and staff to follow through on every take down request like that. Part of the reason of requiring a DMCA is that it adds friction to the take-down process to discourage people from wanting to take stuff down because they "feel like it". Only those who have a very strong desire to take something down will bother with a DMCA.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the mean time it takes to process and enforce a DMCA on SO?

Comment: "You are knowingly violating someone's copyright." TFD, I posted this statement on a blog two years ago. You are knowingly violating my copyright.

Comment: @TFD SO isn't violating anything. The person who posted the question *may* have violated copyright in doing so. The DMCA very explicitly grants this protection to websites that accept content from their users, it calls it "safe harbor", and without it sites like SO could not exist. At all. If something needs to come down, the owners of that content need to follow the appropriate procedures to make that happen. That's the price they have to pay for having their content protected by copyright. If you want to argue that copyright is messed up, I'll agree with you, but this is what we've got.

Comment: @TFD Knowingly violating someone's copyright?! Oh noes!

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson - Personally if the person was willing to post their email on a public forum, regardless of popularity, I believe it should be left as is.

Comment: The OP should take on that responsibility, not the mods. If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, let the OP sort it out. In the end they will be ultimately responsible anyway

Comment: It's probably worth adding that the burden on the content owner to issue a DMCA takedown notice is actually exceptionally *light* by normal legal standards--so light, in fact, that some claim the law is probably unconstitutional on that basis (it's open to relatively easy abuse, and a site may be obliged to take down content to maintain the safe harbor status, even for questionable or clearly false takedown notices).

Comment: The initial burden is very light, you just need to make a claim. But it is similarly easy to file a DMCA counter-claim, in which case the burden gets thrown back on the initial filer, as detailed [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#designatedagent). Anyone with a few minutes free time who likes to cause trouble? :-)

Answer (score -1):

> Don't bother flagging it. It's not a moderator's job or even the site's job to enforce 3rd party agreements.
>
> If someone wants something taken down, they need to file a DMCA request.

I'm no legal expert, but saying copyright infringements are always someone else's problem sounds like incredibly bad advice.

Sure the "safe harbor" stuff and the disclaimers in the usage policies make sense. They're there to cover SE's back, and that's reasonable enough.

However, leaving content that's blatantly infringing copyright or redistributions licences (assuming we're above a quantity that's beyond fair use) does no good to the SE community. The main problem is that readers could, in good faith, assume that the user who posted something had the right to do so, and that content could find its way into other places under the SE licensing conditions, where it should never have been in the first place (thereby causing potential problems to the users using that content).

Overall, it is in SE's interest to prevent such problems to happen to its community. Not having a strict legal requirement to do something doesn't mean that you should stay inert. (In fact, that's why most laws appear: because something is not forbidden and then someone goes too far.)

If I go to my supermarket and my car gets broken into, this will not be the supermarket's responsibility (as clearly stated on signs on its car park). Yet, it's not in the interest of the supermarket to let thieves act in all impunity on its car park.

Comment: Neither suggested edit reviewers or moderators are lawyers, nor can we tell the difference between a troll editing posts citing copyright violations and true takedown notices. The correct action here is for editors to reject the edit; and as a sign of politeness, possibly pointing the editor to the stackexchange.com/legal page in the edit rejection reason, and let the legal team deal with it.

Comment: @Matt, agreed it's not easy. I'm just saying that saying "it's not our problem" isn't the answer. You're talking about rejecting edits. Earlier, I did reject [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5211882), which visibly uses code from a Highcharts plugin, which is not open source. Unfortunately, others had accepted the edit, so it had gone through anyway. While posting the code improves the question indeed, do you really think it's a good thing to let that stuff through, when you know it comes from somewhere that wouldn't let you redistribute it freely?

Comment: The main issue is that someone else, unaware of this licence restriction, could borrow the code from SO assuming it was properly licensed in the first place, and use it in good faith, only to discover too late that they were consequently infringing copyright themselves. This type of issue is *not* a good thing for SO.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is, every edit reviewer should be aware of every piece of copyrighted material out there, just in case it accidentally infringes a distribution licence? I guess if we have the suggested edit reviewers take some kind of legal exam, it would help weed out the robo reviewers.

Comment: @Joe, not at all, I'm suggesting that if they see something they know isn't right, or strongly looks like it (like the edit I was talking about above: clearly a larger piece of code, from other authors, without a licence), they refrain from approving edits. Some people seem to alter so-called "link-only" answers to put the text in, without really thinking too hard whether it's OK to do so. Perhaps a bigger warning when posting something that says "are you sure you're licensed to post this content" would help those who are completely unaware of anything that has to do with copyright.

Comment: I get your point, but it is up to those who are actually liable to deal with these kind of disputes, and not us. How do we know that SE doesn't have an agreement with XXX, which allows them to post code or whatever? We don't know enough to be able to tackle this, so let it go through the official avenues.

Comment: @Joe, it's hard to say what agreements SE may have indeed, but as readers, it's fair to assume the content is published under CC. This in turn could lead to such code making its way within our code or other libraries that we use. That could cause much bigger problems later on (e.g. you've build a large piece of code around a library only to discover there are legal issues around it too late). Not being a copyright holder of the code that was posted, it's not up to us to file a DMCA report. Yet, we can become liable if we start using this stuff without abiding by its licence.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying that moderators should be legal experts or know the origin of all code. I'm saying that it's a grey area and that always dismissing such concerns is a bad idea. (Typical cases that should raise questions typically involve larger pieces of code, since fair use then becomes arguable.)

Comment: The answer is not saying that it's someone else's problem.  The answer is saying that the person is going about removing the content in the wrong way.  If someone wishes for content to be removed because they feel it is violating copyright, they need to use the right tool for the job (a DCMA takedown) and not another tool (such as a suggested edit).  Using the right tool means that the request will be reviewed by the correct people, and handled appropriately.  This is particularly important with issues as complex and with as significant of ramifications as this one.

Comment: @Servy, correct, but my understanding is that DMCA notices can only be sent by the initial copyright holder, whereas I'm saying we should be a bit more careful collectively, when applicable, so as to try to prevent problems further down the line that can potentially affect users oblivious to these issues.