# Dealing with a claim that a post on SO is using copyrighted content without permission

Tags: discussion, legal, dmca-notice

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732528/1469208) (a bit surprising) answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21809336/1469208) has just popped in my review queue. The question contains a photograph and someone stating that they are the photographer posted an answer demanding that the photo is removed.

How should I react on similar claims, that question is using copyrighted content as an example to illustrate their problem?

Should I:

- recommend deletion and do nothing more,
- recommend deletion, but leave comment, that [DMCA request need to be filled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261737/1469208),
- *do something else*.

Original, now deleted post:

> This image belongs to me, Jeremy Smith. It has been used without my consent and I would like it removed from your site within 14 days. It is unlawful to use copyrighted images without the consent of the owner and I am quite within my rights to prosecute. My image can be viewed here http://www.jeremysmithphotography.co.uk/p449844316/hc691c3d#hc691c3d
>
> or on my Flickr page.
>
> Jeremy Smith

Comment: ... While we where pondering, @AndrewT. solved the problem by swapping the image for a similar narrative and more awesome text.

Comment: @Yakk: _"Solved"_? Hardly. See [this comment by @MartijnPieters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809336/make-images-layed-out-as-inline-block-have-on-hover-titles-on-the-bottom#comment42062099_21809336)

Comment: Can somebody post a screen shot of the answer (with the material in question blanked out) so future readers may see the context?

Comment: @Radiodef: in the context of how we should handle this in general, it hardly matters what the exact message was, but I'll see about copying it into the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. So the question contains the copyrighted image and the image's author posted an answer asking for it to be removed. That is what I meant by 'context' I guess.

Comment: @Radiodef: cleaned up the post to bring in a little more context.

Comment: I'd like to tell JEremy Smith (the image owner) that once he posts something on Internet, there will be big chances that someone else gets it and possibly uses it withous his consense.

Comment: @Funkystein that does not somehow magically remove his ownership of it though. Why do you think for example youtube videos regularly get taken down because of using copyrighted music/imagery?

Comment: This doesn't conflict with what I noted. You put your stuff on the net at your risk. Taking down a video requires time, since it's published. People may have enough time to download it and exchange it by other means (sites, cds, pendrives, ...)

Comment: @Funkystein: I'm sure the author is already aware of how easy it is to make copies of digital information. Yet as an author you must find a balance between promotion of your work and the chances that someone will steal your work. They are fully within their right to address copyright infringement, however.

Comment: That's for sure.

Comment: Note that it's not within his rights to 'prosecute'. It's within his rights to *sue.*

Comment: wouldn't it be "fair use" to just use the same image at a much lower resolution?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The answer posted is not an answer and should be deleted.

Leaving a comment that the author should file a DMCA takedown notice would be a nice gesture, but is not required. The [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) lists the contact address to which you should send such notices.

I've left a comment on that answer informing the author what they should do in this case, as well as flagging the post as not an answer:

> To have copyrighted content removed from Stack Overflow, please send a [valid DMCA takedown notice](http://brainz.org/dmca-takedown-101/) to Stack Exchange. See the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) for the designated agent to  whom you should send your notice.

or, if you wanted to have a template to copy for future posts:

`To have copyrighted content removed from Stack Overflow, please send a [valid DMCA takedown notice](http://brainz.org/dmca-takedown-101/) to Stack Exchange. See the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) for the designated agent to send your notice to.`

Last but not least, you should not act on the claim; users and moderators are simply not equipped to handle claims like these, as we cannot distinguish between a genuine copyright claim and a fake one, nor can we see if the poster has a genuine right to post the material *anyway*. That is what the DMCA process is for, leave it to the specialists (aka lawyers) to handle such matters.

Comment: It appears the question has been edited. Should the edit be reverted, since it seems to be too minor?

Comment: @Cerbrus: yes, I rolled that back and left a comment to the editor.

Comment: @gnat: I wish that line didn't look so ugly; I can see that it is easier to copy now for use in a comment, but the newlines are just fine when pasting anyway.

Comment: AFAICT, the actual image being disputed is completely immaterial to the question so any image would do (with the added text to illustrate the point the OP was making), so I don't really see the problem with the edit that replaced the image. Why waste everybody's time with DMCA and lawyers when it really doesn't add anything to the question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the DMCA process works for SO, but here's what I think is another reason why it's so important to go through the DMCA process: the image was uploaded to the SO imgur site. If the copyright claim is legitimate, SO might be obligated to get the image removed from imgur and simply removing the link on the post might not be enough. So, just changing the post to point to a different image without the lawyers finding out about it shortcuts that decision process and might leave SO subject to liability (standard disclaimer: not a lawyer; just guessing here).

Comment: @EuroMicelli Also the image will still be visible in the revision history.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Keeping the content but removing the link shouldn't place liability on SE.  A DCMA takedown notice would still need to be filed; SE would only be liable if they failed to comply with a DCMA notice that the copyright holder filed (even after the edit).  If the content author chooses not to persue his claim after the prominent link is removed, even if the content is still hosted, then that's his decision.

Comment: @servy: you might be right. Under US law. Perhaps. I wouldn't want to take the risk, but that's just me. Send it to the lawyers and let the professionals sort it out.

Comment: I disagree that Andrew T's edit was improper. The flipside of "copyright is not our concern as normal users" is that this claim is now a distraction from the technical substance of the question. By replacing the disputed image with an equivalent that carries no baggage, the entire issue is laid to rest for us normal users, and the lawyers may proceed as they would have anyways. On the other hand, you're quite right that the burden should be on the claimant; we shouldn't reflexively assume that someone crying "my copyright" is correct and take action on that basis.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange Inc. cannot act on copyright claims without a DMCA request without risking loss of their safe harbour protection. That does not mean that the community can not ask people if they feel they have legal justification to post a photo, and discuss the possibility of replacing it.

Taking direct action is not appropriate, and if users can't quickly come to an agreement, then a DMCA request is the only way forward. However, discussions about copyright issues are often framed as though a DMCA request is the only possibility. This can be an unnecessary source of conflict and drama, when a civil discussion could have been sufficient.

Many people these days are simply not aware of copyright issues. **We should first try to educate them**, not put them in an unexpected adversarial situation.

---

Here's a comment I posted on the question under discussions:

> @JohnM: Hi! This is an interesting question. I was just wondering about the example you chose to use. Do you have a license to use that photo? If you aren't sure, would you mind I created an alternative example with a free photo, to be in the clear? I'll make sure the text and everything is lined up exactly as in your example (I notice that the previous suggested replacement did not, and may have misrepresented your intent). If you don't like the result, we can revert it after the fact. Please let me know how you feel about this. Thanks! :)

If it were posted near the beginning of the discussion (I came in late to this one), it would set a much more constructive tone for the discussion than immediately appealing to legal processes. I'd like to see more people considering this approach in the future.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO in such a situation, it could be a nice usage to post the incorrect answer as a comment since to poster could not comment itself (not enough rep). I often do that when a low rep user post a comment as an answer, mostly when he adds *not enough rep to comment*.

But current case has already taken too much importance for me to do that without someone else advice ...

Comment: The comment wouldn't do much now; the OP knows about the copyright complaint. Thats what should have been done before the "answer" was ever posted. At this point, the only thing that would change anything would be a DMCA takedown notice.

Comment: I thing there is an important difference. The photograph can no longer see its own post, nor the comment from Martijn Pieters explaining that he should post his message to the Designated Agent according to the Terms of Service. All he can see is that *power users* or *moderators* of Stack Overflow removed its post.

Comment: A fair point. Users *can* see their own deleted posts though.

Comment: You are right. When I had less rep I completely lost an anwser, but it was because the question had been deleted. Here the photograph should still see its post and Martijn's comment. But it could put some pressure on OP, because **he**  no longer sees anything ...

Answer (score -11):

Jeremy Smith gave yahoo (and it's users and it's API) a worldwide non-exclusive license to adapt, modify, publicly display everything he uploaded when he posted (publicly) to Flickr. He is not within his rights to have the OP's post unilaterally removed, by using that alone.

https://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/utos/utos-173.html  section 9, b.

The poster of the original question simply used a screenshot of a flickr feed in their jsfiddle. The contents of the jsfiddle being dynamically generated content from flickr. And the screenshot may create a separate issue related to the copyright of that image in the screenshot. But this is not clear, does OP get an exemption related to analysis of a work, exemption based on a derivative work, an exemption based on fair use, or is OP exercising their own rights in line with the Yahoo terms of service that they also agreed to in order to use the Flickr api?

It would be naive to believe this has been challenged in higher court at all, in a way that also takes into account United Kingdom laws and United States laws.

So although the actual issue is immaterial to your question, you should realize now the ambiguity of how copyright claims can be, so you should not delete, or delete + leave comment about DMCA, instead you should just leave it and let the lawyers sort it out.

Stackoverflow users also are adhering to a set of terms and should not have to be cognizant of these things that legal needs to sort out themselves.

Comment: That section is not grating a right to SO users to use the contents posted to Yahoo: "you grant **Yahoo** the following worldwide, royalty-free and non-exclusive license(s), as applicable [...] b. With respect to photos, graphics, audio or video you submit or make available for inclusion on publicly accessible areas of the Yahoo Services other than Yahoo Groups, the license to use, distribute, reproduce, modify, adapt, publicly perform and publicly display such Content **on the Yahoo Services solely for the purpose for which such Content was submitted or made available.**"

Comment: `on the Yahoo Services solely for the purpose for which such Content was submitted or made available.` ... including its API ... I already elaborated about the issues it presents.

Comment: As included in the SO page, it is not Yahoo which is doing the distribution.

Comment: @Kendra that the OP shouldn't have the image removed

Comment: @Louis right, and Yahoo's ToS is unclear about what rights members have with Yahoo content except a prohibition on commercial use. So we can fall back to the law, the image in the SO page is a derivative work under US Copyright and is also posted for analysis of the derivative work. This continues to serve the purpose of muddying Jeremy Smith's copyright claim, making a knee jerk reaction of a moderator impossible, and left only to attorneys

Comment: this doesnt answer the question HOW TO HANDLE SUCH AN ANSWER.

Comment: @vba4all you are right, I noticed that halfway down my comment discussion. I thought it was a fun exercise so I'm not deleting it