# How to review this suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Today I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19372945) in the review queue. In the comment the user claims to be from Universal Pictures but nothing in his/her profile suggests this is true.

My question is: How should I handle this specific suggested edit?

Comment: I would reject. If that user is indeed from UP, they'll contact SO directly regarding any copyright matter.

Comment: That is not the correct way to deal with copyright issues.  They can file an DMCA takedown notice, a procedure that this company is well familiar with.

Comment: Noteworthy is that this is the second attempt. [The first one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19357637) was also rejected (well, *someone* approved it), although for the wrong reason "deviates from author's intent".

Comment: Apparently the image was replaced by the OP themself, which might become another problem like "hiding evidence of copyright picture" since it's still on the revision history... Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276013/2821954 (since I had done the same mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of its (alleged) source, the edit attempts to remove an image that serves a valid purpose in the answer – it's an example of the output.

There is a reject reason for this:

> attempt to reply
>   This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

(As the actual *content* of the example image does not seem to bear any relevance to the answer, theoretically it could be replaced with another one. Since in this case the DMCA may need to get involved, that would *not* be a proper solution here – but nor was the suggested edit.)

Comment: Please consider reading [Martijn's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276013/2821954) regarding editing the image (since I had done the same mistake).

Comment: @AndrewT.: I see! It's a valid point, legally-wise – but we also don't want everyone to go on swapping images with "better" ones at their whim. I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to get copyrighted information removed is via a DMCA request. Stack Overflow [provides instructions](https://stackexchange.com/legal#15CopyrightPolicy) for how to do this.

As you say, you do not have the tools to verify whether this kind of edit is valid so you should probably reject it. If you wish you could try to contact the editor to suggest that they go about things the right way instead.

Comment: Mentioning the editor in a comment won't work in this case if I read your link correctly: _"Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions)."_