# Should I flag questions that are recruitment tests?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, ethics

I found a question where an algorithm is posted, and its problem is

> 14% mark in codility

The question's merit notwithstanding, I googled "codility" and apparently it's a platform where recruiters can give candidates programming tasks.

So, asking a question that came from a place like that is likely an infringement of trust of some sort, though we can't be sure (could be an already failed task that the candidate is still wondering about).

Should I flag something like that? Or is it the asker's responsibility?

Comment: It could also be an infringement of copyright.

Comment: *could be an already failed task* - That's what "14% mark in codility" means. From the FAQ, it looks like you don't get that score until after you've finished the assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the site's FAQ, this specific site allows candidates to consult books and web sites but not *people*. They're expected to work on their own.

So reading existing Q&A on Stack Overflow might be OK but posting a new question about their task to pass the assessment would violate their rules.

However, the asker said that their score was 14%, meaning that they've already finished this assessment. They aren't cheating; the test is over.

Generally speaking, I don't think we have to worry about too many people trying to cheat online assessments by asking a question:

1. They're usually timed and there's a very small window for completion, 1-2 hours. Getting someone on Stack Overflow to do it for you instead in that window would require a lot of luck. Not impossible, but someone relying on this runs the very real risk of no one who can answer even seeing it in time.
2. Someone trying to get an answer within 1-2 hours probably wouldn't have any of their own code or very little. This would likely result in their question being Too Broad (any answer would be too long) or Unclear (it's unclear what the issue is). Many users hate questions that are just a task.
3. Even someone who wanted to answer wouldn't necessarily get the right answer before time expired.
4. It would be especially difficult for new users under 125 rep because the system only allows them to ask once every 90 minutes and these tests generally consist of multiple tasks.

I think attempts to cheat are going to result in bad, off-topic questions that can be handled in the usual way.

As far as copyright issues go, per Heretic Monkey:

> Moderators won't do anything about copyright violations unless the
>   holder files a DMCA request to remove it. See [Dealing with a claim
>   that a post on SO is using copyrighted content without permission](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276012/dealing-with-a-claim-that-a-post-on-so-is-using-copyrighted-content-without-perm/276013#276013).

Comment: Since the copyright issue was not my original concern, I'm accepting this answer (and thank you for your argumennts), though the copyright issue might still be worth discussing like you said.

Comment: Moderators won't do anything about copyright violations unless the holder files a DMCA request to remove it. See [Dealing with a claim that a post on SO is using copyrighted content without permission](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276013/215552)

Answer (score 10):

If it is not a copyright violation, I don't see any reason to be concerned.

If the test is online, you would expect users to use online resources in solving the problems.

If the test is not online, and is administered in such a way that online resource can be used to solve them, still not a problem.

If the test is confidential, and there is a privacy agreement, it is not our scope to address.

If it is a copyright violation see [Does SE containing copyright violations make content re-use harder?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114275/217279)

Related:

- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2112418)

Comment: I don't think I would expect users to use online resources in solving an online test, same as I wouldn't students taking a "home test" to use online resources.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I dunno... for me (in Canada) the VERY intent of a home test is to give you full access to whatever you want to fix it....

Comment: James says he is not concerned when he checks in to the hospital and the surgeon confesses "This will be first time I got the opportunity to use a knife.  But don't worry, I never made a mistake yet".  Two broken legs could bring that to a good end.  Or rapid application of anesthesia, the SO way.

Comment: "*If it is not a copyright violation, I don't see any reason to be concerned.*" there is an `ethics` tag, so there *might* be a reason to be concerned beyond copyright.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I think it's incredibly unfair and weird to expect people to do a coding test without allowing external resources. In in-house interviews I've helped conduct, we allowed applicants to look at *any* online resource. I found this is a lot easier for both all. I want to see if they are able to solve programming problems not quiz them on how well they've memorised some API that might not not even be relevant day to day. I basically have one tab open in my browser on some form of documentation at any time I'm writing code anyway - why would I expect an applicant to not do it.

Comment: @VLAZ I stand corrected, let me rephrase - using online resources like documentation is legitimate in a test, but there has to be a limit... Copying the answer from a tutorial, for example, cannot be ethical. The question was where's SO on this spectrum - I'd put it in the farther end, but that's the discussion

Comment: @ItamarMushkin what kind of test author would include questions, where answers in a tutorial? Or not create new questions regularly, the instructor and/or test writer, are employed positions. If the exact questions and answers are on the internet, or in the tutorial, it speaks to the weakness of the test givers not the test takers.  See some related Q&A at [Preventing leaking exam papers/cheating using phone cameras?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23099) where the top voted answer says in part "Publish online all previous exams as an exercise book."